# Oracle SQL Concatenate multiple entries with different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, join, concatenation

i have two tables

firstTable:

| Row | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

secondTable:

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Text1 |
| 2 | Text2 |
| 3 | Text3 |
| 4 | Text4 |
| 5 | Text5 |
| 6 | Text6 |

Expectation would be to get a view like this

| Row | ConcatinatedText |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 text2 text3 |
| 2 | text4 text5 text6 |

Do you have an idea how i can achieve this with an statement in oracle?
This is all i have till now...but i don't know how i can proceed...
I thought i can work with Alias in the concatination..but i don't know how to use these to get the text through the different IDs...

```
select ID1text || ' ' || ID2text|| ' ' || ID3text||' '||
from firstTable join secondTable
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You have to join the secondTable 3 times, once for each id column.

Comment: ... or use three  *subqueries* and concatenate them.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. But can you maybe give me an example how to use this ALIAS for this text in the join? So that i can use it in the concatination? I really have no idea :/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to join the secondTable three times, you can use below alternative which is using ***Unpivoting*** clause to first unpivot the **firstTable** (columns ID* --> rows), and then joining it with the **secondTable** . All you have to do after that step is to group that result per "row" column, and use the **Listagg** aggregate function to concatenate texts as you need.

```sql
with firstTable_Unpivoted ( "Row", ID, source_column ) as (
    SELECT "Row", ID, source_column
    from firstTable
    unpivot (
        ID for source_column in (
            ID1 as 'ID1'
        ,   ID2 as 'ID2'
        ,   ID3 as 'ID3'
        )
    )
)
select 
    FTU."Row"
  , listagg(ST.Text, ' ') within group (order by FTU.ID) ConcatinatedText
from 
    firstTable_Unpivoted FTU
left join 
    secondTable ST
        on FTU.ID = ST.ID
group by FTU."Row"
;
```

[demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1c9b5ccf8819a1c3d0ccfad9fb8cf2a6)

Answer (score 0):

For *small* tables you may safe use a *subquery* to fetch the text value for each`ID`and concatenate the result.

**Example with Sample Data**

```
with t1 as (
select 1 id, 1 id1, 2 id2, 3 id3 from dual union all
select 2,4,5,6 from dual),
t2 as (
select rownum id, 'Text'||rownum text from dual connect by level <= 6)
/* Your Query */
select 
 id,
 (select text from t2 where id = t1.id1)||' '||
 (select text from t2 where id = t1.id2)||' '|| 
 (select text from t2 where id = t1.id3) as  concTxt
from t1;

        ID CONCTXT                                                                                                                               
---------- --------------------- 
         1 Text1 Text2 Text3                                                                                                                     
         2 Text4 Text5 Text6
```

Otherwise as commented use three joins, which produce the same result possible more performant for *larger data*.

```
with t1 as (
select 1 id, 1 id1, 2 id2, 3 id3 from dual union all
select 2,4,5,6 from dual),
t2 as (
select rownum id, 'Text'||rownum text from dual connect by level <= 6)
/* Your Query */
select 
 t1.id,
 t21.text ||' ' || t22.text || ' ' || t23.text as concTxt
from t1
join t2 t21 on t1.id1 = t21.id
join t2 t22 on t1.id2 = t22.id
join t2 t23 on t1.id3 = t23.id
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I will test it later :)

Comment: Thank you it worked fine in Oracle. Do you have an idea if its possible to write this query with JPA?

Comment: For sure it is possible to use in JPA. Either use *names query* or capsule the logic in a *database view* and query it in JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Below query is bit dynamic and just need to add how many columns you need in filter condition:

T11:[image]
T12:[image]

```
SELECT   row_id
        ,LISTAGG( text, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)
FROM     (WITH
              aa
              AS
                  (SELECT ids
                         ,row_id
                   FROM   t11 UNPIVOT (ids FOR id1 IN (id1, id2, id3)))
          SELECT *
          FROM   aa
                ,t12
          WHERE  aa.ids = t12.id)
GROUP BY row_id
```